# Integrating $\int _0^1\frac{\ 1}{\sqrt{\ 1-x^2}}\sin ^{-1}\left(2x\sqrt{\ 1-x^2}\ \right)dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I'm sorry if this is a simple question. if anyone can correct me, I'd greatly appreciate it. So first i used substitution $x = sin\theta$ so we have

$$\int _0^{\frac{\pi }{2}}\frac{\ 1}{\sqrt{\ 1-\sin ^2\theta }}\sin ^{-1}\left(2\sin \theta \cos \theta \ \right)\cos \theta d\theta$$

$$\int _0^{\frac{\pi }{2}}\ \sin ^{-1}\left(\sin 2\theta \right)d\theta $$
cancelling out $\sin^{-1}(\sin 2\theta)$ we are only left with $2\theta$ so aren't we supposed to get
$$\int _0^{\frac{\pi }{2}}\ 2\theta d\theta $$ which leaves us with $2\left[\frac{\ \theta ^2}{2}\right]$ for bound from 0 till $\frac{\pi }{2}$ so I get $\frac{\pi ^2}{4}$ but my answer is wrong according to my text book it says it should be $\frac{\pi ^2}{8}$ but how? where did i go wrong?

I even shaded the area we are interested in finding area of [image]

Comment: In $\int _0^{\frac{\pi }{2}}\ \sin ^{-1}\left(\sin 2\theta \right)d\theta$  perform the change of variable $x=2\theta$ and look at the interval of definition of $arcsin$ function.

Comment: Note that $\arcsin(\sin x)=x$ hold true for all $0\leq x\leq \frac{\pi}{2}$ however, $ 0\leq 2x \leq  \pi$  so the $\arcsin(\sin2x)\neq  2x$

Comment: Ohhh Noted @Naren Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is in your attempt to simplify $\sin^{-1}\bigl(\sin(2\theta)\bigr)$ to $2\theta$.

For $0\le\theta\le{\large{\frac{\pi}{2}}}$, we get
$$
\sin^{-1}\bigl(\sin(2\theta)\bigr)
=
\begin{cases}
2\theta&\text{if}\;0\le\theta\le\frac{\pi}{4}\\[4pt]
\pi-2\theta&\text{if}\;\frac{\pi}{4}\le\theta\le\frac{\pi}{2}\\
\end{cases}
$$
so you need to sum two integrals, one for each of the above cases, yielding
$$
\int_0^{\large{\frac{\pi}{4}}} (2\theta)\,d\theta
+
\int_{\large{\frac{\pi}{4}}}^{\large{\frac{\pi}{2}}} (\pi-2\theta)\,d\theta
=
\frac{\pi^2}{16}
+
\frac{\pi^2}{16}
=
\frac{\pi^2}{8}
$$

Answer (score 1):

In $\displaystyle \int _0^{\frac{\pi }{2}}\ \sin ^{-1}\left(\sin 2\theta \right)d\theta$  perform the change of variable $x=2\theta$ and look at the interval of definition of $\displaystyle \arcsin$ function.

Answer (score 1):

If you plot the integrand $$f(x) = \frac{\sin^{-1} 2x \sqrt{1-x^2}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$ on $x \in [0,1]$, you will discover that there is a cusp around $x = 0.7$.  Here is a picture:

[image]

What's going on?  Well, on $[0,1]$, the function $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ is smooth, so that isn't the issue.  This suggests that there is something going on with the inverse sine.  Specifically, how do the plots of $$g(\theta) = \sin^{-1} (\sin 2\theta), \quad h(\theta) = 2\theta$$ compare?  If $\theta = \pi/4$, then $\sin 2\theta = 1$, the local maximum.  So when we take the inverse sine, we don't get $2\theta$ back; we get an angle in $[-\pi/4, \pi/4]$.

So to handle this issue, we have to be a bit more careful with the substitution.  On $\theta \in [0,\pi/4]$, which corresponds to $x \in [0, 1/\sqrt{2}]$ (because the substitution is $x = \sin \theta$, hence $\theta = \pi/4$ means $x = 1/\sqrt{2}$), the integrand does indeed simplify to $$\int_{x=0}^{1/\sqrt{2}} f(x) \, dx = \int_{\theta = 0}^{\pi/4} 2\theta \, d\theta.$$  But on $x \in [1/\sqrt{2}, 1]$, we have instead $$\int_{x=1/\sqrt{2}}^1 f(x) \, dx = \int_{\theta = \pi/4}^{\pi/2} 2(\pi/2- \theta) \, d\theta.$$  These two pieces are equal; their sum is $\pi^2/8$ as claimed.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the arcsin is a function and will only output values that are less than or equal to $\frac{\pi}{2}$. In the case of $\sin^{-1}(\sin(2\theta))$ for $0 \le \theta \le \frac{\pi}{2}$ the cancellation that you made of $\sin^{-1}(\sin(2\theta))=2\theta$ is invalid. As you can see on the graph:
[image: sin cancellation]
For this you must integrate from $0 \le \theta \le \frac{\pi}{4}$ and multiply the answer by two.

Not the most rigours explanation but hope this helps out a bit.

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \sin^{-1} 2x\sqrt{1-x^2}$$
Let $x=\sin t, t=2u$ then
$$I=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\pi} \sin^{-1}\sin u du =\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{u}{2}+\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi} \frac{\pi-u}{2}du =\frac{\pi^2}{8}.$$